# I am unable to alter table engine while importing SQL dump file in clustered environment it generates error

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql-cluster

I am importing the SQL dump file in MySQL NDB Clustering Environment All the tables are imported successfully on node1. but they are not clustered on node 2. For this execute the following command:

```
Alter Table su_contribution ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER;
```

This command is executed successfully with some tables but not with all tables with some tables it generates the error:

I want to import the dump sql dump file but facing these issues:

Comment: So... you're not facing any issues? Or where are they?

Comment: Assuming node1 and node2 refers to two MySQL servers (mysqld ), does node2 also have table su_contribution defined but using another engine? Use `SHOW CREATE TABLE sy_contribution` in same database on node2.